# In SQL is the syntax UPDATE ...SET (field1, field2, field3) = (value1, value2, value3) a standard syntax?

Tags: sql, syntax, sql-update

I am using SQLITE and postgres, and i've found that the following syntax:

```
UPDATE my_table

SET (field1, field2, field3) = (value1, value2, value3) -- i.e. SET "fields tuple" = "values tuple"

etc...
```

works fine (and I like it a lot);

Is it standard SQL? 
Which databases support this syntax, "how much standard" is it?

Comment: Yes, that's part of the ISO standard for SQL. Oracle and DB2 also support this.

Comment: Postgres also supports this syntax -- and multiple assignments with subqueries which is why this is particularly useful.